# How I can pass exception stack trace from gRPC server?

Tags: c#, microservices, grpc, grpc-c#

I have a microservice built with dotnet core framework, added ExceptionHandler Interceptor to catch application level exception, but struggling to send back my error stack trace.

I tried pushing exception using below syntax -

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
  return new RpcException(new Status(StatusCode.Internal, "Error occurred", ex));
}
```

Any clue or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried *throw new RpcException(...)* instead of *return*? Exceptions are ususally thrown, checkout [the MS Docu on raising gRPC exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/error-handling#raise-errors-in-aspnet-core-grpc)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, that's the only way to send the stack trace over gRPC. You can include it as part of the Status object, as you stated.

You can then access the inner exception using

```
RpcException.Status.DebugException
```

Please check this response from one of the grpc project contributors https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/25740#issuecomment-1015305096

He explains that RpcException.InnerException is only a mechanism to help with debugging and future implementation plans.